Auth successful with invalid redirect_uri using react oidc from axa
Issue and Steps to Reproduce
With the following configuration for OIDC:
const configuration: OidcConfiguration = {
 client_id: 'movies-app',
 redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/authentication/nonsense`, // Invalid redirect URI
 // silent_redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/authentication/silent-callback`,
 scope: 'openid offline_access', // offline_access scope allows client to retrieve refresh_token
 authority: 'http://localhost:8080/realms/company-services',
};

And the following router configuration:
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <HomePage />,
  },
  {
    path: '/admin',
    element: (
      <OidcSecure>
        <BaseLayout />
      </OidcSecure>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        element: <Home />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

Authentication is still successful, even though the redirect_uri is set to an invalid path /authentication/nonsense, and service workers are not enabled. How is this possible.
Steps to Reproduce

Configure the OIDC setup with the provided configuration object.
Initiate the authentication flow by navigating to the /admin route.
Observe that the authentication is successful, despite the invalid redirect_uri.

Versions
"@axa-fr/react-oidc": "7.22.0-alpha.1416",
